# How do I convert a camelCase string to underscore in java keeping some upper cases and the rests as lower cases?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, camelcasing

How do I convert a camel case string to underscore in java keeping some upper case letters? I'm usin this code:

```
String inputString = "Hi How areYouToday";
String result = inputString.replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z]+)", "$1_$2");
```

I can convert inputString in `Hi How are_You_Today`, but, I need to get `Hi How are_you_today`.

Notice that only converted part is changed to lower case version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Matcher#appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) and pass dynamic replacement, based on what was found by regex.

I also changed your regex a little bit, to not include lowercase part in match, but accept only uppercase character which is preceded by lowercase character. More info at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

```
String text = "Hi How areYouToday";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]").matcher(text);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "_"+m.group().toLowerCase());
}
m.appendTail(sb);

System.out.println(sb.toString()); //Hi How are_you_today
```

---

OR Since Java 9

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]").matcher(text);
String result = m.replaceAll(match -> "_" + match.group().toLowerCase());
```

because construct

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb, /*replacement for each match*/);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String result = sb.toString();
```

was wrapped into [Matcher#replaceAll​(Function replacer)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) so it can be used as

```
String result = m.replaceAll( (MatchResult match) -> /*replacement for each match*/ );
```

Comment: what if we want to change UpperCameCase to underscore style like `AreYouToday` to `are_you_today`?

Comment: @sajjadG if we have `"Hi How areYouToday";` should `Hi` and `How` also be reduced to `hi` and `how`?

Comment: Yes please :-) I used your snippet and changed regex to `([A-Z]([a-z]+))` and executed against the input right after your snippet added `_` to change the case to lower. it's working but it's two different regex for different things. I think it's possible to write a regex to do them both together (changing from CamelCase to underline and lowering all the cases).

Comment: @sajjadG You can use something like https://ideone.com/8Wk3Dw. Idea is that we want to check if before uppercase is a-z, or space/start-of-the-string. Second case after `trim()` operation will result in empty string. If it is a-z then we need to add `_` between, if not we just add matched uppercase converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

split inputstring into 2 using substring or split() and use replace all on individual string