# Java Lucene query from Camel to snake case

Tags: java, lucene

I have some Lucene queries that I need to convert fields from camel to snake case,

e.g.

"fullName:John Smith" -> "full_name:Jhon Smith"

"(myTitle:foo bar AND myBody:quick fox) OR title:fox" -> "(my_title:foo bar AND my_body:quick fox) OR title:fox"

String replace is not an option, I have plenty of fields.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to perform a one-time change to your Java source code files (using any relevant text processing tool)? Or are you looking for a utility that will perform the conversion for you on-the-fly in the Java code itself, based on an approach such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050696/12567365)? Why does "I have plenty of fields" mean "string replace is not an option"? I don't see the connection between these two things.

Comment: Also, I am not sure why this is tagged as a Lucene question - that does seem incidental to what you want to do.

Comment: @andrewjames ... could be more string parsing than lucene question. Agree. 

One option is doing string replace for all fields, right ?  like 

StringUtils.replace(query, "myTitle", "my_title")

I am looking for some Lucene parser ... so I can iterate over the fields and update them.

Comment: Understood. As far as I know, there is no Lucene parser/analyzer/etc. which can rewrite a query string in this way. That is outside the scope of Lucene. I would wrap your query strings in a method call and then use the logic mentioned in the previous link. There would need to be some extra logic to split out the field names from each `fieldName:some text` - and then you can use that linked `fieldName` to `field_name` logic. But how that might work, for your specific needs, depends on aspects of your code which are not shown in the question.